# JBPM Task Event Lister Registration

Tags: events, task, jbpm, event-listener

I am using JBPM 6.2 core engine in our application.

I wanted to use my own Custom Task Event Listener to execute my own java code.

I didn't find any documentation so that I can use with JBPM core runtime engine. I found multiple places to use with console and define in deployment descriptor.

Please help!

Answer (score -1):

We can register Task event Listener at RuntimeManager level or at TaskService level.

1. > ```
   > TaskService taskService = runtime.getTaskService();
   >         ((EventService<TaskLifeCycleEventListener>)taskService).registerTaskEventListener(new DefaultTaskEventListener() {
   >             @Override
   >             public void afterTaskAddedEvent(TaskEvent event) {
   >                 System.out.println("taskId = " + event.getTask().getId());
   >             }
   >         });
   > ```
2. At RuntimeManager level:

> RuntimeEnvironment environment =
>   RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.getDefault()
>                   .persistence(true)
>                   .entityManagerFactory(emf)
>                   .userGroupCallback(userGroupCallback)
>                   .addAsset(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(process),
>   ResourceType.BPMN2)
>                   .registerableItemsFactory(new DefaultRegisterableItemsFactory() {
>                       @Override
>                       public List getTaskListeners() {
>                           List listeners = super.getTaskListeners();
>                           listeners.add(new DefaultTaskEventListener() {
>                               @Override
>                               public void afterTaskAddedEvent(TaskEvent event) {
>                                   System.out.println("taskId = " + event.getTask().getId());
>                               }
>                           });
>                           return listeners;
>                       }
>                   })
>                   .get();
>           return RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newPerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager(environment);